# Dynamic module won't pause when toggled (version update problem?)

Tags: dynamic

I ran this code in 2019 to give my students a simple Fourier filtering exercise.  It generates some multi-tone sound data, then plays the tone (allowing the user to pause the playing, since the tone gets annoying).  Then we filter out the higher or lower tone and listen to the difference.  I've posted below only the data generation and sound playing code.  But now, four years later, the module won't pause when you toggle the play/pause icon.  I haven't changed the code, so is this a version update problem?

```
tData = Table[i 0.00012, {i, 0, 1023}];
yData = Table[ 
   0.1 Sin[2 Pi 440 i 0.00012] + Sin[2 Pi 1400 i 0.00012], {i, 0, 
    1023}];
sound = ListPlay[yData, SampleRate -> 8333];
DynamicModule[{state = "pause"}, 
 Grid[{{Toggler[
     Dynamic@state, {"pause" -> Style["\[RightPointer]", 24], 
      "play" -> Style["\[FilledSmallSquare]", 16]}], 
    Dynamic@If[state == "play", 
      If[ScheduledTasks[] == {}, RunScheduledTask[EmitSound[sound]]]; 
      "playing", 
      If[ScheduledTasks[] != {}, 
       RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]]; "paused"]}}]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Version 11.2 `ScheduledTasks`, `RunScheduledTask`, and `RemoveScheduledTask` where superseded by the function `Tasks`. Currently I'm running Mathematica Verison 13.1 and the following code will toggle whith the dynamic play/pause icon.

```
sampleRate = 8000;
tData = Table[i /sampleRate, {i, 0, sampleRate - 1}];
yData = Table[0.1 Sin[2 Pi 440 i /sampleRate] + Sin[2 Pi 1400 i /sampleRate],{i,0,sampleRate - 1}];
plotData = Transpose[{tData, yData}];
ListPlot[plotData, Joined -> True, Frame -> True]
ListPlot[plotData, Mesh -> All, Joined -> True, 
MeshStyle -> {Black, PointSize -> Medium}, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 0.01}, All}]
sound = AudioStream[Audio[ListPlay[yData, SampleRate -> sampleRate]]];
DynamicModule[{state = "pause"},
Grid[{{
 Toggler[
  Dynamic@state,
  {"pause" -> Style["\[RightPointer]", 24], 
   "play" -> Style["\[FilledSmallSquare]", 16]}
  ],
 Dynamic@If[state == "play",
  AudioPlay[sound, Looping -> True]; "Playing",
  AudioStop[]; "Paused"
  ]
}}]]
```

Note that I've opted to use `AudioPlay` and `AudioStop` (added in Version 11.2) leaving the module independent of `Tasks`.